# The difference between policy injection and exception policies in Entlib

Tags: enterprise-library, code-injection, policy

I'm sure this is a real newbie question, but I am a little confused. Are Policy Injection with the PIAB, and the exception policies you can enter into EntLib config or the .config file - the same thing or different?  Does the config utility use the PIAB to create and process the exception policies, or are they two different things?

Thanks,
Peter